# Centering multiple line text in JavaFX label

Tags: java, text, javafx, alignment, label

I'm struggling to center my multiple line `Label` in JavaFX.
I splitted each line using `\n`, and I can't center the whole text.
I've been trying to use `label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER)`but it just doesn't work.

Here is what I've got:
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx......
xxxx..........

this is what I need:
xxxxxxxxx
...xxxxxx...
.....xxxx.....

I know it has to be a better solution than filling labels with unnecessery spaces.

Comment: `setAlignment` changes the alignment of the control. Use `setTextAlignment` instead

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)

Comment: Create an answer and accept it.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188); a [screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) will make it easy to see the effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `setAlignment`. You don't want to just align the `Label` itself, but the text within it. Try `setTextAlignment` instead.